# Reading a 3D model with texture

Tags: 3d, blender, meshlab

I have a 3D model (.obj) with it's texture (.jpg image) and an .mtl file. I'm trying to read it using Meshlab or Blender. For this I use File->Import .obj. I read that the texture is loaded automatically, however only geometry is read. You can find in this link ( http://filex.univ-nantes.fr/get?k=64lROZKoUzmaslol3hR ) the 3D model with his texture if needed. I will be thankful if someone could explain why this 3D model can't be read or could show how to read it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no texture for the model. The image with the model is an example render of a complete textured model, the obj file has nothing more than two colours, white for the bottle and yellow for the lid.

Depending on your needs, the sample render can be used as a texture for the front and back. While there should be extra product info on the back you can use the same image on the back if your needs are simple. Note that the image has permanent highlights so will look out of place from some angles.

[image: textured bottle in blender]

[Bottle in blend file.](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50104)

Comment: So the image in the folded isn't the texture. I understand. Can you explain how did you transform the image in the folder into texture and how did you applied it ? thanks

Comment: @Anass78314 While it wasn't used as a texture, you can use any image as a texture, I UV unwrapped the model and aligned the UVs to the image, then created a material that used the image. You can find plenty of tutorials explaining UV unwrapping a model.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'll check a tutorial.

Comment: Another question, How can I export from the .blend  an .obj + .png (texture) + .mtl file ? I did a "file -> export obj", however only geometry and .mtl were generated. No .png or .jpg was generated.  Should I export the image texture separately . ?

Comment: exporting to obj doesn't copy the image texture. Copy the image with the obj file, you may need to adjust the image path saved in the mtl file.

Comment: yes I made the export to .obj, I placed the image in the same folder and I fixed path into .mtl file to the image. When Import into the .obj file into blender, the image isn't applied to the 3D model..